Unable to find base configuration section in build settings on Xcode 14.3
Hey I am trying out a project and am using Flutter for the first time. I need to change the appropriate file for Debug, Release, and Profile in the base configuration section under build settings on XCode. This would be in my runner target. I came to build settings but am not able to find a base configuration section. Using XCode 14.3.
Tried to create a custom .xcconfig file and manually set it as the base configuration. Too confusing. So wanted to revert and see if I just missed the base configuration section.

describe more ?

@markhorrocks If you use CocoaPods: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/147263

write this up to get the bounty. I did figure how to add includes to the files in my Podfile as  a workaround but your answer is the issue.
